# reverse_cuthill_mckee permutation on sparse coo_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, permutation, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix in the coo format, defined with the three vectors `(I, J, V)` that represent each matrix entry.
To concentrate the pattern around the diagonal, I first evaluated the `reverse_cuthill_mckee` permutation (I converted the matrix in CSR format); then, I applied the permutation to `I` and `J`. The new matrix, however, differs from the one I would obtain if I apply the permutation with block indexing (first converting to a CSR format). e.g., in the example code `A2_rcm` has the pattern I'm expecting, while `A_rcm` is a completely different one.

[patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjudF.png)

I wonder if it is possible to apply the permutation directly on `(I, J, V)`.

Thanks.

Cesare

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, ,coo_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import reverse_cuthill_mckee
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__=='__main__':
    npt       = 100
    fmat      = sparse.rand(npt, npt, density=0.02,random_state=1234)+np.eye(npt)
    A0        = coo_matrix(fmat.transpose() * fmat)
    I0        = A0.row
    J0        = A0.col
    V0        = A0.data
    perm_rcm  = reverse_cuthill_mckee(csr_matrix(  (V0,(I0,J0)),shape=(npt,npt)  ),symmetric_mode=True).astype(np.int32)
    iperm_rcm = np.zeros(shape=npt,dtype=np.int32)
    for js,jt in enumerate(perm_rcm):
        iperm_rcm[jt] = js
    assert np.all(perm_rcm[iperm_rcm] == np.array(range(perm_rcm.size)))   
    I_rcm   = perm_rcm[I0].astype(I0.dtype)
    J_rcm   = perm_rcm[J0].astype(J0.dtype)
    V_rcm   = V0
    A_rcm = coo_matrix((V_rcm,(I_rcm,J_rcm)),shape=(npt,npt))
    A2_rcm = A0.copy()
    A2_rcm = A2_rcm.tocsr()[perm_rcm[:,None], perm_rcm]
    A2_rcm = coo_matrix(A2_rcm)

    mks = 2.0
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
    ax1.spy(A0,markersize=mks)
    ax1.set_title('Before permutation',fontweight='bold')
    ax1.set_xticks([0, npt//2, npt])
    ax1.set_yticks([0, npt//2, npt])
    
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
    ax2.spy(A_rcm,markersize=mks)
    ax2.set_xticks([0, npt//2, npt])
    ax2.set_yticks([0,  npt//2, npt])
    ax2.set_title('After permutation (coo)',fontweight='bold')

    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
    ax3.spy(A2_rcm,markersize=mks)
    ax3.set_xticks([0, npt//2, npt])
    ax3.set_yticks([0,  npt//2, npt])
    ax3.set_title('After permutation (csr)',fontweight='bold')


    plt.show()
```

Comment: Obviously with something this complex (and the fact that I have not explored reordering - except years ago in MATLAB), I can't visualize what's happening by just reading your code.  Either you need to show some of the arrays, or figures, or I have to fire up a session and do that testing myself.  One thing to watch out for is the mapping between `coo` and `csr` indexing.  A canonical csr matrix has sorted row and columns.  I don't recall if the `random` matrix values are sorted or not.

Comment: SciPy automatically cats between CSR and COO matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I found the answer: the permutation looks like it is on the target matrix, to obtain the original one; e.g.

```
    A_rcm[perm,perm] = A0
```

Hence, I have to apply the inverse permutation to obtain the matrix with smaller bandwidth. The code to obtain the matrix after the permutation thus becomes:

```
    A0        = csr_matrix(  (V0,(I0,J0)),shape=(npt,npt)  )
    perm_rcm  = reverse_cuthill_mckee(A0,symmetric_mode=True).astype(np.int32)
    iperm_rcm = np.zeros(shape=npt,dtype=np.int32)
    for js,jt in enumerate(perm_rcm):
        iperm_rcm[jt] = js
    I_rcm   = iperm_rcm[I0].astype(I0.dtype)
    J_rcm   = iperm_rcm[J0].astype(J0.dtype)
    V_rcm   = V0
    A_rcm = coo_matrix((V_rcm,(I_rcm,J_rcm)),shape=(npt,npt))
```

Comment: Your `iperm_rcm` is `perm_rcm.argsort()`

Answer (score 1):

What I was trying to explain in the comment is that upon the automatic conversion from coo to csr, the data elements, and indices are reordered.  You can't simply apply an reordering developed for a csr format to the original coo.

To illustrate, make a `random` matrix:

```
In [81]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.1)    
In [82]: M
Out[82]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [83]: M.row
Out[83]: array([6, 9, 4, 2, 2, 9, 7, 9, 0, 8])    
In [84]: M.col
Out[84]: array([8, 7, 2, 9, 5, 2, 7, 1, 2, 6], dtype=int32)
In [85]: M.data
Out[85]: 
array([0.11481564, 0.61345662, 0.73757165, 0.70870704, 0.10107628,
       0.21206099, 0.99050484, 0.49029339, 0.03697263, 0.58873489])
```

And it csr:

```
In [86]: Mr = M.tocsr()    
In [87]: Mr.data
Out[87]: 
array([0.03697263, 0.10107628, 0.70870704, 0.73757165, 0.11481564,
       0.99050484, 0.58873489, 0.49029339, 0.21206099, 0.61345662])    
In [88]: Mr.indices
Out[88]: array([2, 5, 9, 2, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 7], dtype=int32)
```

The order in the `Mr.data` is different from the `M.data`.

Having said that, I don't know what `perm_rcm` is, or how it's supposed to be used.  I'd have to take time to explore an unfamiliar part of the sparse package.

If I convert the csr back to coo, the indices retain the csr order:

```
In [89]: M1 = Mr.tocoo()
In [90]: M1.col
Out[90]: array([2, 5, 9, 2, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 7], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: yes, however, the equivalent full matrix structure is kept; e.g.: entry (6,8) will still be  0.11481564. The reverse_cuthill_mckee permutation acts on the indexes of the full matrix and permutes the indices of the entries to reduce the dispersion along the diagonal. E.G., I'm expecting that `perm_rcm` will map (6,8) to perm_rcm[6], perm_rcm[8] (perm_rcm has as many elements as the matrix size since it is a renumbering of the matrix indexes).
The two operations are conceptually the same, however, it works only for CSR matrices